# Getting Ruby environment variables from Rake

Tags: ruby, rake, environment-variables, rakefile

I have a Rakefile which has tasks for deploying or building an application. This Rakefile is used in both production and development.

I would like the `build` task to know what the environment is. Can this be done without passing a parameter to the task when I run it? Can it be done with environment variables?

When in development, I need the task to look like this:

```
task :build => :clean do
  compass compile -e development
  jekyll
end
```

And in production, like this:

```
task :build => :clean do
  compass compile -e production
  jekyll
end
```

Comment: Yes, rake tasks should have access to `ENV`.

Comment: I have never used `ENV`, so if someone could kindly demonstrate how I would set the variable (and get it). I'm a ruby n00b.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can use environment variables. Here's skeleton implementation:

```
task :build do |t, args|
  puts "Current env is #{ENV['RAKE_ENV']}"
end
```

Usage:

```
% rake build
Current env is 

% RAKE_ENV=development rake build
Current env is development
```

Comment: Do I have to specify `RAKE_ENV` every time I run the command, or can it remember for me?

Comment: ENV includes all environment variables known to a new process. So if you put that var into a `.profile` (or whatever init file you use), it will be remembered across system restarts. You can choose any name, by the way, not necessarily RAKE_ENV. Just make sure it's unique enough, so you don't overwrite any other env var.

Comment: Do I just create a `.profile` file in my project directory or is this a system wide thing?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: it's system-dependent. Different systems (and shells) use different files. But this is a bit off-topic here. You should ask that (how to persist env var) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Cheers. http://superuser.com/questions/539913/how-to-persist-ruby-environment-variable